# AngularJS: ngView inside a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-view

I'm trying to use `ng-view` inside a custom directive but it's not working and it's also not giving me any console error.

This is my directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('header', Header);

    Header.$inject = ['USER_AGENT'];

    function Header(USER_AGENT) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: 'app/shared/header/header.html',
            controller: controller
        }

        function controller($scope) {
            $scope.isMobile = USER_AGENT.isMobile;
        }
    }

})();
```

And inside `header.html` file I have a call to `ng-view` just like I was calling it outside (when it was working).
Is it possible to nest `ngView` inside a custom directive?

Comment: Not sure if this can be worked out or not, but, IMHO, this is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm wondering wether your directive should be applied to an element instead so restrict : 'E' , and usage <header></header> ? But I agree with the last comment usually you want ng-view in the index.html file... not in a directive

Comment: Yes, I know that, but in this case I really need it that way. And if I make <header></header> probably I'll have some IE restrictions.

Comment: Have you tried to simulate a `$rootScope.$broadcast('$routeChangeSuccess', nextRoute, lastRoute);` by yourself? maybe that works (even if its pretty dirty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS does not support multiple `ng-view`s in one app. If you want it - you have to use another routing engine, for example Angular UI's [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Comment: As long as you understand how `ngRoute` works, you can make it work with multiple views: http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/11/11/understanding-angularjs-directives-part2-ng-view/

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could use it you shouldn't because is not the correct approach for Angular a `directive` should be treated like a *web component* like `input`, `select`, etc.

Just remember that your `header.html` is just a view and can be used by pretty much anything, is just the view

```
.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'app/shared/header/header.html',
    controller: controller
});
```

Or (using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router))

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/?accountkey',
    templateUrl: 'app/shared/header/header.html',
    controller: controller
});
```